# Rank nullity inequality proofs

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the Linear Transformations $f: V\rightarrow W$ and $g: W\rightarrow X$ and I should prove:

$$dim(ker(g\circ f)) \geq dim(ker(f))$$
$$dim(Im(g\circ f)) \le dim(Im(f))$$

I know that one immediately follows from the other and I tried proving it using the rank-nullity theorem, but I failed until now.

To prove the second statement I deduced this from the rank-nullity theorem:

$$dim(Im(g\circ f)) \leq dim(V)$$
but I am pretty sure that $V\neq Im(f)$ so I do not know where to go from here. Any help would be very kindly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I Hope f and g are Linear Transformation right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V,W,$ and $X$ are vector spaces and $f:V\rightarrow W$ and $g:W\rightarrow X$ are linear transformations, then $$Ker\ f\subseteq Ker\ (g\circ f)$$ this dues to the fact that if $f(v)=0$, then $g\circ f(v) = g(f(v))= g(0) = 0$, which is a consequence of the linearity. For this reason, it follows that $$dim\ Ker\ f \le dim\ Ker\ (g\circ f) .$$

For the second inequality, observe that $$dim\ V = dim\ Ker\ f+dim\ Im
\ f$$
$$dim\ V = dim\ Ker\ (g\circ f) + dim \ Im\ (g\circ f).$$

Now subtracting the first one form the second one, we get $$dim\ Ker\ (g\circ f ) - dim\ Ker\ f = dim\ Im\ f - dim\ Im\ (g\circ f).$$
Now, as we proved, the left hand side should be positive and, therefore, so should be the right hand side, as we wished to prove.

Comment: Remember that for linear transformations, we have $g(0)=g(0+0)=g(0)+g(0)\implies g(0)=0$

Comment: Hmm thank you very much! I think I see now... Is it because of $f(c*x) = c*f(x)$ would not hold, if e.g. $f(0) = 1$, because then $f(5*0) \neq 5*f(0)$ ? Edit: Just saw your edit, thanks again :)

Comment: Yes! It would be a contradiction

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\ker(f)\subseteq\ker(g\circ f)$, which provides the first inequality.

Then, by rank-nullity,
$$
\dim\operatorname{Im}(g\circ f)=
\dim V-\dim\ker(g\circ f)
$$
Now use the first inequality and rank-nullity again.